# Sort from database tables by multiple checkbox php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about display data from the database alphabetically. 
I have 2 ckeckboxes and if the nr.1 is checked, it must display data alphabetically from table "companyName" but if chechbox nr.2 is checked, it must display data alphabetically from table "stade".

I am very new to coding, so I will be happy if there was someone who could explain or show me exactly how it should look.

Here is the checkboxes:

```
  <fieldset>
    <dl">
        <dt><label for="sleep">Sortering:</label></dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Alfabetisk A-Z"/>
            <label for="alfabetiskA-z" class="opt">Alfabetisk A-Z</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Alfabetisk Stade"/>
            <label for="alfabetiskStade" class="opt">Alfabetisk Stade</label>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</fieldset>
```

Here is where I show my data fra the database:

```
 echo '
              <table class="tableUser">
                <tr class="topColor">
                  <td>Stade</td>
                  <td>Firmanavn</td>
                  <td>Navn</td>
                  <td>Telefon nr.</td>
                  <td>E-mail adresse</td>
                </tr>';


              $class0 = "trColor0";
              $class1 = "trColor1";

              $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM creatUser ORDER BY companyName ASC");

              while( $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $id = $result['id'];
                $class = "trColor". $i%2;

                echo '

                <tr class="'.$class.'">
                  <td VALIGN=TOP>'.$result['locationNumber'].'</td>
                  <td VALIGN=TOP>'.$result['companyName'].'</td>
                  <td VALIGN=TOP>'.$result['fName'] . ' ' . $result['lName'].'</td>
                  <td VALIGN=TOP>'.$result['phone'].'</td>
                  <td VALIGN=TOP>'.$result['eMail'].'</td>
                </tr>';
                $i++;


              }
```

Comment: What if they check both boxes? Maybe you should use a radio button instead of checkboxes.

Comment: I can do that, but I still do not know how to do it, like I said I am very new to coding

Answer (score 0):

You have to give names to your checkboxes, so you can get what the user selected:

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort" value="Alfabetisk A-Z"/>
        <label for="alfabetiskA-z" class="opt">Alfabetisk A-Z</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort" value="Alfabetisk Stade"/>
        <label for="alfabetiskStade" class="opt">Alfabetisk Stade</label>
```

Then in your PHP, you do:

```
if (!isset($_POST['sort']) || $_POST['sort'] == 'Alfabetisk A-Z') {
    $order = 'companyName'
} else {
    $order = 'stade';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM creatUser ORDER BY $order ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: You need a submit button to submit the form.

Comment: Any PHP tutorial should explain how to write and process forms.  I'm not going to try to teach you all the basics of doing this here.